# PostAsJsonAsync ignoring JsonProperty name attribute

Tags: c#, json, httpclient

I have a static method that posts data as follows:

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostExAsync<TValue>(this HttpClient client, string path, TValue value, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return client.PostAsync(path, null, ct);
    }
        
    return client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, value, ct);
}
```

With the above code, the `JsonProperty(Name)` attribute is ignored. If I change the code as follows:

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostExAsync<TValue>(this HttpClient client, string path, TValue value, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    var json =  value != null ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value) : null;
    var content = value != null ? new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") : null;

    return client.PostAsync(path, content, ct);
}
```

It works. But why is the first method not working? I would rather use the first method instead of the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that `PostAsJsonAsync` uses the `System.Text.Json` library, which has its own attribute: [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0#customize-individual-property-names).

In your second example, you're using JSON.NET, so given that it's working as you expect, it seems that your model is decorated with [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonpropertyname.htm).

If you want to use System.Text.Json everywhere that the model is used, then you should be able to just change your attributes to the ones from System.Text.Json. Otherwise, you could potentially decorate your property/properties with attributes for both libraries.

Comment: Can I decorate the models with both attributes?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do that.

Comment: @IvanDebono - *Can I decorate the models with both attributes?* -- sure, but watch out for the fact that some of the attributes such as `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverterAttribute` and `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverterAttribute` have the same name!  If you are going to apply both I recommend removing `using Newtonsoft.Json` and/or `using System.Text.Json` from the top of your file and using fully qualified names for the attributes.